# c# Fractional Calculator - Working out Box?

Tags: c#, calculator, box

I'm working on a project where I need to develop a fractional calculator.
I want to add something extra to it, such as having a working out box that displays how the user got their answer.

For example, say I enter 1 1/2 + 1 1/2 into the calculate and press "Calculate", it would then display the answer and how it got the answer such as:

> = 3/2 + 3/2
>   = ((3 × 2) + (3 × 2)) / (2 × 2) 
>   = (6 + 6) / 4
>   = 12/4
>   = 3/1
>   = 3

Here is my basic, crappy looking, program: http://gyazo.com/1dc27b531873c48cdb198baa40b3af9a

I want it to display the working out in the 'Calculations' box below.

How am I able to do this?

Comment: You are not sharing any source code, and not asking for a specific problem (rather, how to write a whole program, which is too big for 1 post).

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 2 anyway? 3/2 + 3/2 = 6/2

Comment: What do mean? I've already written the program but I don't know how to do what I stated above. The other code is irrelevant.... Also http://gyazo.com/047111d61b2356bd8560a1e805630028 @ Yazanpro

Comment: Please do not use external links to document your question; besides the web security issues, they make the question harder to understand, and most importantly, they are not guaranteed to be preserved, rendering the question hard or impossible to understand in the future. A Stack Overflow question should be entirely self-contained, with links to external resources used only for non-critical, optional information.

Comment: As far as the other issue with your question: please provide _here_ [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the question. Explain precisely what you've tried so far, what that code does, and how that's different from what you want it to do. Your question needs to be more specific than "how do I implement this feature?" Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: Side note: What is the logic in your calculation? The numbers started out with a common denominator, but you doubled it anyway without checking? Shouldn't it be: `3/2 + 3/2 = (3 + 3) / 2 = 6/2 = 3`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is missing some details, so here is a simple answer to begin with.
(I guess your GUI is winforms, and you have a trigger for the calculate OnClick)

To add text into your "Calculations" textbox the code you need is (for your example):

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int common_den = denumerator1*denumerator2;
    int new_enumerator1 = enumerator1 * denumerator2;
    int new_enumerator2 = enumerator2 * denumerator1;

    string myCalculations = " = " + enumerator1.ToString() + "/" + denumerator1.ToString() + " + " + enumerator2.ToString() + "/" + denumerator2.ToString();
    string myCalculations += " = " + new_enumerator1.ToString() + "/" + common_den.ToString() + " + " + new_enumerator2.ToString() + "/" + common_den.ToString();
    string myCalculations += " = " + (new_enumerator1 + new_enumerator2).ToString() + "/" + common_den.ToString();



    calculationsTextBox.Text = myCalculations;
}
```

- If you are looking for the code that will build the calculation string - you need to ask for it explicitly

Comment: Yeah, something like that but instead of actual text it would call the varibles Numerator and Denominator etc. I'm looking for the code that will build the calculation string but I'm unsure how to implement it.

Comment: string myCalculations = "= " + numerator1.ToString() + "/" + denumerator1.ToString() " + " + numerator2.ToString() + "/" + denumerator2.ToString() + " = "; // etc.

Comment: if you need the math for the code:

`int common_den = denumerator1*denumerator2;`

`int new_enumerator1 = enumerator1 * denumerator2;`

`int new_enumerator2 = enumerator2 * denumerator1;`

Comment: You might consider finding the LEAST common denominator rather than the greatest...